# How to trim / edit a video and save with original settings, without encoding

Tags: video, video-editor

I have several videos from which I want to trim the end. Usually it takes too long time – so I need software that does not change the original settings and does not re-encode.

For example if my video 720×576, encoded with H.264  at 25 fps and a bitrate of 8000, these settings should remain – also for sound – and it should export as quickly as possible.

Comment: also, here is a very useful article on the subject: http://www.echeng.com/journal/2016/10/2/trimming-h264-mp4-video-files-without-re-encoding

Answer (score 1):

[MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-win.html) does exactly that